# AlertDialog on android v4.2.2 and v2.3.6

Tags: android, eclipse, android-alertdialog

Can anyone know why is **AlertDialog** on android **4.2.2** differ from  android **2.3.6**? I try to export the game in those android versions. what I get is on the 4.2.2 the AlertDialog can be cancel by just clicking outside of the frame while on the 2.3.6 is that the AlertDialog works fine and cant be cancel unlike on the 4.2.2.

here's the code actually:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle(context.getText(R.string.finished_title));
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.finish, null);
builder.setView(view);
final AlertDialog finishDialog = builder.create();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable(boolean)

Comment: dialog.setCancellable(false);

Comment: it was very helpful. tnx sir Pozzo.